# Awk print file name within for loop

Tags: for-loop, awk, filenames

I am running a for-loop over several files located in a directory.  Each command within the for-loop appends the former .txt with a new column.  Currently, the 3rd line in the for loop creates a column with the filepath, but I want just the filename - I don't need the file extension either.  I've played around with splitting and piping back into awk, but no luck.

After adjusting the awk command to get just the filename, I want to then make a master .txt file that contains all looped values.  Essentially I think I would need to append a .txt file with the output from each loop.  Right now that's what I'm trying to do with the pipe in the third line of the for loop, but it just creates an empty .txt file.

```sh
for file in ~/Desktop/test/*bam
do
    bedtools multicov -bams "$file" -bed bed_for_multicov.bed >  "${file%%_RRemoved.bam}_counts.txt"
    awk '{print $0,a}' a="$(samtools view -c "$file")" ${file%%_RRemoved.bam}_counts.txt > ${file%%_RRemoved.bam}_CPMcounts.txt
    awk -v var="$file" '{print $0, var}' ${file%%_RRemoved.bam}_CPMcounts.txt > ${file%%_RRemoved.bam}_CPMcounts2.txt | >> CPMcountsMaster.txt
done
```

Current filename1_CPMcounts2.txt output

```
chr1    11088   11488   peak_1  192 4409922 path/to/filename1.bam
chr1    20674   21215   peak_2  217 4409922 path/to/filename1.bam
chr1    28550   28862   peak_3  170 4409922 path/to/filename1.bam
chr1    29582   30300   peak_4  437 4409922 path/to/filename1.bam
chr1    30635   31720   peak_5  696 4409922 path/to/filename1.bam
chr1    32373   35541   peak_6  2877 4409922 path/to/filename1.bam
```

Current filename2_CPMcounts2.txt output

```
chr1    11088   11488   peak_1  293 5888360 path/to/filename2.bam
chr1    20674   21215   peak_2  439 5888360 path/to/filename2.bam
chr1    28550   28862   peak_3  392 5888360 path/to/filename2.bam
chr1    29582   30300   peak_4  901 5888360 path/to/filename2.bam
```

Desired filename1_CPMCounts2.txt output

```
chr1    11088   11488   peak_1  192 4409922 filename1
chr1    20674   21215   peak_2  217 4409922 filename1
chr1    28550   28862   peak_3  170 4409922 filename1
chr1    29582   30300   peak_4  437 4409922 filename1
chr1    30635   31720   peak_5  696 4409922 filename1
chr1    32373   35541   peak_6  2877 4409922 filename1
```

Desired Final CPMcountsMaster.txt

```
chr1    11088   11488   peak_1  192 4409922 filename1
chr1    20674   21215   peak_2  217 4409922 filename1
chr1    28550   28862   peak_3  170 4409922 filename1
chr1    29582   30300   peak_4  437 4409922 filename1
chr1    30635   31720   peak_5  696 4409922 filename1
chr1    32373   35541   peak_6  2877 4409922 filename1
chr1    11088   11488   peak_1  293 5888360 filename2
chr1    20674   21215   peak_2  439 5888360 filename2
chr1    28550   28862   peak_3  392 5888360 filename2
chr1    29582   30300   peak_4  901 5888360 filename2
```

Comment: The variable is [`FILENAME`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Auto_002dset).  See also POSIX [`awk`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html); `FILENAME` is a standard built-in variable there, too, so it is likely available in most versions of `awk`.

Comment: Why does `Desired Final CPMcountsMaster.txt` has more lines then `Current filename2_CPMcounts2.txt output`? Just pipe the last column via `basename the_file .bam`. Are you sure the script you presented works?

Comment: If you want the basename as the 'filename' output, then replace `a="$(samtools view -c "$file")"` with `a=$(basename $(samtools view -c "$file") .bam)"`.  Note that one of the advantages of the modern `$(…)` notation is that it is much easier to nest invocations than if you use the old back-ticks notation for command substitution.

Comment: Filename is coming from the 3rd line, not the line including samtools.  I tried FILENAME earlier, but it did not work within my for loop - it called the name of the .txt file (not the $file in the loop).

Comment: As a general comment I'm a bit confused about the output you get and the usage of your variable substitution. Eg. You use ${file%%_RRemoved.bam} which seems to imply that the filename, stored in $file ends with the string RRemoved.bam. You last awk passes the same variable, but in the output we don't see this string.

You also have command | >> outputfile. This is invalid syntax. Always try to parse your code first with https://shellcheck.net. It saves lives!

Answer (score 1):

The following works, adapted from J Leffler's comment - thanks!

```
for file in ~/Desktop/test/*bam
do
    bedtools multicov -bams "$file" -bed bed_for_multicov.bed >  "${file%%_RRemoved.bam}_counts.txt"
    awk '{print $0,a}' a="$(basename "$file" _RRemoved.bam)" ${file%%_RRemoved.bam}_CPMcounts.txt > ${file%%_RRemoved.bam}_CPMcounts2.txt
    awk '{print $0,a}' a="$(basename "$file" _RRemoved.bam)" ${file%%_RRemoved.bam}_CPMcounts.txt >> CPMcountsMaster.txt
done
```

Comment: How does this work, this is not even the same as your original script?